# How to access a global $SiteConfiguration variable in PHP from everywhere?

Tags: php, scope, configuration-files

I share the PHP code base across all pages and for each HTTP request I dynamically `require` the `"/configs/$site/config.php"` file. The file looks like this:

```
<?php
$SiteConfiguration = [
  'site_title => 'Wiki for Developers',
  'mysql_host' => 'localhost',
  'mysql_db' => 'wiki-devs',
  'articles_per_page' => 10,
  /* ... etc ... */
];
?>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't quite access this variable from functions.

For example:

```
function DisplayArticles() {
    echo "Displaying ".$SiteConfiguration['articles_per_page'];
}
```

It will print just `Displaying` and not `Displaying 10`.

How can I fix this and have my $SiteConfiguration accessible everywhere? Should I use a `class`? What's the best practice here?

Comment: The terms to google for are _"dependency injection"_. By no means a simple topic, but a whole architecture theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
global $SiteConfiguration;
```

in your function, you can find some more info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Since you asked for best practice info: (simplest form)

```
class MySite{
    public static function getConfig(){
       return array(
       'site_title => 'Wiki for Developers',
       'mysql_host' => 'localhost',
       'mysql_db' => 'wiki-devs',
       'articles_per_page' => 10,
       /* ... etc ... */
       );
    }
}
```

then in your code you can recall it with

```
$config = MySite::getConfig();
```

and use it. (obviously with a better, more descriptive name than MySite ;) )

Advantages:

1. your php class [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) will automagically load it for you if setup correctly and your classes can be found, this means not worrying wether you passed a variable, not worrying about function argument placement and not tainting your functions with unnecessary arguments that don't help describe what it does.
2. you control exactly the access to this data and can make it so that not even your own functions can accidentally change this data, not even when calling other functions that would also need access to it.

in my opinion it beats globals and it beats passing via arguments since it's cleaner and you control the access to it in all forms. You can make certain attributes readonly/writable via specific getter/setter options, keep count of how many times it's accessed and whatever else you can think of.

Comment: Would that be the best practice in my case? I hear often that I should avoid the `global` keyword.

Comment: honestly globals are almost never a good idea, if you want to share singular data using a singleton pattern would be better. it allows for better control of your data and how/when you alter and use it.

Comment: the main thing is that with a global you can replace it with anything, say you have $db_connection and you accidentally put a string in it somewhere. Suddenly your app starts to failand such errors are very hard to trace since you'll have like dozens of places where you use the global. Whereas with the singleton it'll return the object but you won't be able to replace it, safeguarding it for correct use.

Comment: if you want a good example, look at how SMF handles their database connections versus how yii does it, the cleanliness of a singleton pattern and the ease of debugging should immediately be apparant. http://www.simplemachines.org/ vs http://www.yiiframework.com/  fight! ;)

Comment: @bodacydo: does this make sense to you? :)

Comment: It does make sense. Your explanation is great. I'm already applying it in my code! :)

Comment: good, I'm not a native english speaker and I wonder if I make enough sense to you guys sometimes. At times I find it hard to correctly convey my ideas and concepts in my head. :)

Answer (score 0):

[use global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
function DisplayArticles() {
    global $SiteConfiguration;
    echo "Displaying ".$SiteConfiguration['articles_per_page'];
}
```

Edit

You should try to avoid global variable.

A better practice would be to pass your array in parameter

```
function DisplayArticles( array $config ) {
    echo "Displaying ".$config['articles_per_page'];
}


$SiteConfiguration = array( 'site_title' => 'Wiki for Developers',
                            'mysql_host' => 'localhost',
                            'mysql_db' => 'wiki-devs',
                            'articles_per_page' => 10,
                            /* ... etc ... */
                          );

DisplayArticles( $SiteConfiguration );
```

Comment: Would that be the best practice in my case? I hear often that I should avoid the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another case where a class for configuration would work great:

```
class Config {
    private static $site_config = array( 'h' => 'Hello', 'w' => 'World');

    public static function get( $key) {
        return isset( self::$site_config[$key]) ? self::$site_config[$key] : null;
    }
}

echo Config::get( 'h') . ' ' . Config::get( 'w');
```

This will output: `Hello World`

Comment: you can use "self" (instead of "Config" ) keyword inside "Config" class when you access it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Your "siteConfiguration.php" file:

```
<?php
    $SiteConfiguration = [
        'site_title' => 'Wiki for Developers',
        'mysql_host' => 'localhost',
        'mysql_db' => 'wiki-devs',
        'articles_per_page' => 10
    ];

    return $SiteConfiguration;
?>
```

And this function:

```
function getConfigVar($var) {
    static $config = array();

    if( empty($config) ) {
        $config = require("siteConfiguration.php");
    }

    return array_key_exists($var, $config) ? $config[$var] : null;
}
```

This function can also be modified to handle several configs.